# CSS element do not hide second bloks

Tags: html, css

Why "zawartosc prawo" do not hide "zawartosc lewo"? on hover effect?
I try change class name, add ID, and another, but still do not work :(

Maybe I must try add some JS? But I think someone know how to do this.

Code

```css
.zamieniamlewo {
  display: none;
}

.prawo:hover ~ .zamieniamlewo {
  display: block !important;
}

.lewo:hover ~ .prawo {
  display: none;
}

.zamieniamprawo {
  display: none;
}

.lewo:hover ~ .zamieniamprawo {
  display: block !important;
}

.lewo {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.prawo {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lewo">
  <h3>Zawartość lewo</h3>
</div>


<div class="prawo">
  <h3>Zawartość prawo</h3>
</div>

<div class="zamieniamlewo">

  <h3 class="imie">zamieniamlewo</h3>

</div>

<div class="zamieniamprawo">

  <h3>zamieniam prawo</h3>

</div>
```

Comment: **prawo** does not proceed **lewo** which is a requirement for the general sibling selector (`~`) to work. The selector cannot look backwards into the DOM.

Comment: I agree with @hungerstar. Source: http://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling

Comment: Though I should note that I do not see a selector for **prawo** to hide **lewo**. I'm assuming you used the sibling selector based on your use of the sibling selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need some thing like this , i have used jquery as it seems pretty straight forward to use when you usually deal with events

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lewo").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".prawo").hide();
        
    });
    
    $(".lewo").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".prawo").show();
         $(".lewo").show();
    });
    
    $(".prawo").mouseenter(function(){
        
         $(".lewo").hide();
    });
    
    $(".prawo").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".prawo").show();
         $(".lewo").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.zamieniamlewo {
    display: none;
}

.zamieniamprawo {
    display: none;
}
.lewo:hover ~ .zamieniamprawo {
    display: block !important;
    background:white;
}

.prawo:hover ~ .zamieniamlewo {
    display: block !important;
     background: white;
}
.lewo {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
.prawo {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="lewo">
        <h3>Zawartość lewo</h3>
      </div>


      <div class="prawo">
        <h3>Zawartość prawo</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="zamieniamlewo">

        <h3 class="imie">zamieniamlewo</h3>

      </div>

      <div class="zamieniamprawo">

        <h3>zamieniam prawo</h3>

      </div>
```

Comment: Ok this is nice, I hace secend question, how to add to your code fadeout()?
fadeOut();

$(".lewo").show();
$("lewo").fadeOut(); ?

Comment: Ankit, but how to add nice fadeout? Could you help me? :)

Comment: Normal fareout effect for class="zamieniamlewo" so I Think must do fadeIN for class="prawo"

Answer (score 1):

The `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

for example:

```
.red ~ p{

  color:red;
}
```

---

```
  <p>i m not red</p>
  <p class='red'>i m not red</p>
  <p>i m red</p>
  <p>i m red</p>
```

here the last two paragraphs match the sibling selector.

So in your code you can change something like

```
 <div class="prawo">
    <h3>Zawartość prawo</h3>
  </div>

   <div class="lewo">
    <h3>Zawartość lewo</h3>
  </div>
```

---

and add this in `.css` file

```
.prawo:hover ~ .lewo {
    display:none;
}
```